# MVC Layout model design pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Every page in my site should have some of the same data, similar to how in SO every page displays info about the current user at the top of the page. The way I implemented this was to have a base controller class that all my controllers derive from. In that base controller's constructor I put my model in the ViewBag, and then my layout page uses that.

I'm running into problems with this because my layouts aren't strongly typed. For example, I have to construct new HtmlHelpers in the layout page:

```
@{var layoutHtml = new HtmlHelper<LayoutModel>(Html.ViewContext, Html.ViewDataContainer); }
@* OK, now we can use the html helper... *@
@layoutHtml.TextAreaFor(model => model.Feedback)
```

I really don't want to have to have my models subclass from a layout model, since that would force each action to fill out the shared model data individually, but manually creating HtmlHelpers also seems like a bad idea.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but shouldn't you use **partial views** for this?
Your solution looks way too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

A base controller is a great way to start. I would also introduce a base viewmodel. The base viewmodel would contain user specific information.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string CurrentAccountName
    {
        get
        {
            return (HttpContext.User == null) ? null : HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }

    public T CreateViewModel<T>() where T : BaseViewModel, new()
    {
        T viewModel = new T
        {
            UserName = CurrentAccountName
        };

        return viewModel;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewModel
{        
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then on each request you would populate your viewmodel with user specific information and whatever information is required for the view. MyViewModel is just a viewmodel that inherits from BaseViewModel.

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel viewModel = CreateViewModel<MyViewModel>();

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

In the master view I would pass in the BaseViewModel and the View I would pass in the inherited MyViewModel.

Now you have access to your user information in your master view and can pass it to a partial or render it directly to the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can define multiple Layouts which you can use in your appropiate views! Just include them like so:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MySubLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can use RenderAction to solve this problem. Because information this action will display is common on all pages, you can put it in BaseController and call it from your site master. it will compute its own model and return that model to partial view which can be strongly typed and you don't have to instantiate htmlHelper the way you are doing now.